# How to group splitter columns by count?

Tags: python, pandas

After splitting data by delimiter I got different columns count.
For example first line from file can have 5 columns, the third 4 columns and etc.

How to group rows by count of columns after splitting and create the corresponding dataframes.

Input data is rows:

```
18 olga australia
12 vasily
15 gamaka
30 gobush germeny strauth 4000
```

As result I need to get three dataframes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What else, I have provided a dataset, and I need to create a some datasets from this. By count of columns, so group rows by count of rows. It sounds better

Comment: how the output should look like?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem - when you split line then use `len()` to check number of values and add it to dictionary `data[ len(row) ].append(row)`. And later you can covnert them to three dataframes

Answer (score 2):

When you split line then you could use `len(row)` to put it in dictionary with lists

```
data[ len(row) ].append(row)
```

And after sorting all rows you can convert every element to `DataFrame`

---

Minimal working code.

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and run it - but you should use `open()`

```
text = '''18 olga australia
12 vasily
15 gamaka
30 gobush germeny strauth 4000'''

import io

data = {}

#with open(filename) as fh:
with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        row = line.split(' ')
        if len(row) not in data:
            data[ len(row) ] = []
        data[ len(row) ].append(row)

#print(data)

for key, val in data.items():
    print('\n--- len:', key, '---\n')
    print(val)
    # here create DataFrame
```

Result

```
--- len: 3 ---

[['18', 'olga', 'australia']]

--- len: 2 ---

[['12', 'vasily'], ['15', 'gamaka']]

--- len: 5 ---

[['30', 'gobush', 'germeny', 'strauth', '4000']]
```

Comment: Do you know hwo to do that using Pandas? I mean I already splitted data using Pandas and there are first dataframe Pandas. Should I iterate over dataframe rows then?

Comment: I have no idea what you have in `dataframe` but if it need to read line by line then there i s no need to use DataFrame to split it but simpler is to create dictionary and later convert every element to DataFrame.